Why symbols are not appending in order?
string_to_translate: dict ={
"a":"@",
"b":"6",
"c":"¢",
"d":"p",
"e":"€",
"f":"√",
}

while True:
    sentence_to_translate: str = str(input("Wpisz zdanie: "))
    sentence_after_formatting: list = [char for char in sentence_to_translate]
    translated_sentence: list = []
    for y in string_to_translate.keys():
        for x in sentence_after_formatting:
            if y == x:
                translated_sentence.append(translated_sentence[y])
            
    print(translated_sentence)
    break

When I type, for example, "fed", I'm getting ['p', '€', '√'], where it should be ['√', '€', 'p'].
Why is this happening? Thanks for help

You're iterating over string_to_translate outside of your iteration over sentence_after_formatting, so the order of items in string_to_translate takes priority. Don't do that.

There's no good reason to iterate over keys in string_to_translate at all; you can do O(1) lookup to get direct to the associated value.

I'd replace the whole thing with print(''.join([ string_to_translate.get(c, c) for c in input("Input: ") ])). And give string_to_translate a better name -- it's a dict, not a string; it should be named something more like translation_table.

(change .get(c,c) to .get(c,'') in the above comment to ignore characters not found in the table)

You're very close to the ideal answer if you wish to translate keys in the dictionary to their corresponding values. Your confusingly named dictionary gets you 99% of the way there. You just need to use str.maketrans and str.translate.
>>> string_to_translate: dict ={
... "a":"@",
... "b":"6",
... "c":"¢",
... "d":"p",
... "e":"€",
... "f":"√",
... }
>>> t = str.maketrans(string_to_translate)
>>> "Hello".translate(t)
'H€llo'


Note that the OP's original code appears to be written to delete characters not present in the translation table.

I suspect that is a side-effect of the OP seeming to only test with strings that contain nothing but characters which are keys in the dictionary.


Why is this happening?

Because you're appending letters to translated_sentence according to the key order of (confusingly named) dict string_to_translate, whereas the order you expect would come from ordering according to input string sentence_to_translate.

Main problem is u firstly check dict's keys if your key in sentences then it adds to your list. So, basically, your code is looking one by one to keys in char list.  To fix that problem, your loop should start with your char and then check if it is  indict or not.
So, your code should be like that :
string_to_translate: dict ={
"a":"@",
"b":"6",
"c":"¢",
"d":"p",
"e":"€",
"f":"√",
}

while True:
    sentence_to_translate: str = str(input("Wpisz zdanie: "))
    sentence_after_formatting: list = [char for char in sentence_to_translate]
    translated_sentence: list = []
    for char in sentence_after_formatting:
        if char in string_to_translate.keys():    
            translated_sentence.append(string_to_translate[char]) 
                 
    print(translated_sentence)
    break
            

